# How to test passwords against a word list with fuzzing

Tags: security, password, password-management

How can I test passwords against a dictionary / word list, where the entries have been fuzzed to some degree?

By "fuzzed", I mean variants of words with "l33t" conversions and other character conversions are included in the check.

Ideally, I would like to pass in a password value, have the utility check the password, and return a yes/no value.

Comment: What did you want it to return?  Are you just looking to see if the password would be in a common rainbow table?

Comment: your using the word fuzz incorrectly.  Fuzzing is a type of software testing.  You mean to say Brute Force.

Comment: You are talking about a dictionary attack with transformations.  Any time you are relying on making a ton of guesses to break the secuirty system you are doing brute force,  in this case it is intelligent brute force.   I have written fuzzers and I can tell you they are completely unrelated.

Comment: sorry for the delay on accepting an answer. I still need to test.

Answer (score 3):

[John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) has modes which can be used to test password strength against a fuzzed list.  It supports creating your own fuzzing rules, and uses whatever dictionaries you provide.  It comes by default with a large set of common fuzzing rules installed, including 1337 transformation, word flipping, doubling, uppercasing, simple number/symbol appending, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you search google for your password and you find even 1 result, then you have chosen a weak password.  **NO ONE** should know your password,  even if they don't know that its yours.

For testing remote system for weak passwords I highly recommend [THC-Hydra](http://freeworld.thc.org/thc-hydra/).  I have used this software in penetration tests with great success.

Answer (score 0):

JTR only applies to hashes, if you're looking to do a little more of a 'penetration test' across the network. Hydra by THC is widely known Network password cracker (But note, With all the extensions, You will be waiting a VERY long time to find even the simplest passwords).